# EFAULT or EDESTADDRREQ for multiple dispatch_io_writes in GCD queue

Tags: ios, posix, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to implement a file storage queue subsystem, as described in wwdc 2012 Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC. I have a custom concurrent processing queue that formats the data and hands over the result to my custom concurrent storage queue. The storage queue then creates an dispatch_io_t channel for writing, splits the file (if I don't split the file I get memory issues with large data), and writes each chunk with a dispatch_io_write. Sometimes the write completes without errors, but often I get either `EFAULT` or `EDESTADDRREQ` for any one of the chunks

My general approach is outlined as follows:

```
dispatch_async(processingQueue, ^{

// prepare dispatch data for storageQueue

dispatch_async(storageQueue, ^{

    dispatch_io_t writeChannel = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM,
                                                              [pathString UTF8String],
                                                              O_RDWR|O_CREAT, // read-write, create if not exist
                                                              S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO, // set all permissions
                                                              storageQueue,
                                                              ^(int error) {

                                                              });

    __block size_t chunkSize = STORAGE_WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE;

    __block off_t currentOffset = 0;

    dispatch_io_set_high_water(writeChannel, chunkSize);

    for (currentOffset = 0; currentOffset < imageDataSize; currentOffset += chunkSize) {

        // is dispatch_barrier required?
        dispatch_data_t blockData = dispatch_data_create_subrange(dictData,
                                                                  currentOffset,
                                                                  MIN(imageDataSize - currentOffset,chunkSize));


        if (dispatch_data_get_size(blockData) > 0) {

            dispatch_io_write(writeChannel,
                              currentOffset,
                              blockData,
                              storageQueue,
                              ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error){

                              });

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Error chunking data for writing!!");
            break;

        }
    }

    dispatch_io_close(writeChannel,0);
});
});
```

I have tried using serial queues, wrapping in `dispatch_barrier` blocks, modifying the `dispatch_io channel` flags, but the problem persists - frequent errors in `dispatch_io_write` due to bad address or destination

Would like to have some answers to:
1. What is the recommended way of doing buffered file writing using `dispatch_io_write` and a custom concurrent queue?
2. Do I need to use `dispatch_barrier`, and if so, `dispatch_io_barrier` of the channel or `dispatch_barrier_async` of the queue?
3. Are there any channel flags that I should be aware of in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong in your snippet. There should be no need to chunk the data manually and submit multiple write operations (dispatch IO already does this internally more efficiently), and I have never heard of those specific IO errors being encountered before.

Please file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with a runnable testcase that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case using DISPATCH_IO_STREAM flag you create stream-based channel, that don't support random access, any offset value (currentOffset) is ignored and data is written at the current file location (0 in you snippet) as described [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH5-SW1).